# Get the latest date record

Tags: sql, date

I have two tables in my SQL Database.

```
ID  CDATE  
1   12/04/14  
2   14/05/14  
3   20/01/14  


ID  NAME  
1    A  
2    A  
3    B
```

But I need the output as below.

```
NAME  CDATE  
A     14/05/14  
B     20/01/14
```

Do you have any suggestions for me ?

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried, and what you are having truoble with.

Comment: You must have tried *something*.  Please edit your question with your attempts.  (Hint:  this is a basic SQL query with a `join` and `group by`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.cdate, t2.name
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id=t2.id
ORDER BY t1.cdate DESC;
```

Edit:

```
SELECT s1.cdate,
  t2.name
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT ID, MAX(cdate) cdate FROM table1 GROUP BY ID
  ) s1
ON s1.id=t2.id
ORDER BY s1.cdate DESC;
```

Comment: I guess this query will list all the rows..but I want to eliminate those that are old. I want only the record that was created latest

Comment: Do you want the two oldest?

Comment: No the latest one for every entry of ID

Comment: @user2037445 Then please edit your question to specify this, as it is clearly not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(t1.CDATE), t2.NAME FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID GROUP BY t2.NAME ORDER BY t1.CDATE DESC
```

Comment: I guess this query will list all the rows..but I want to eliminate those that are old. I want only the record that was created latest.

Comment: @user2037445, see my answer. You need to do a `select top 2`.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Since you changed the question...

```
SELECT TOP 2 n.NAME, d, CDATE
FROM Dates d
LEFT JOIN Names n ON d.ID=n.ID
ORDER BY d.CDATE;
```

Comment: I think op wants, for each name, the latest corresponding date in his first table. Your query works for the dummy sample, but doesn't accomplish that for larger datasets. But I reckon the question is of very poor quality.

Answer (score -1):

To Make table you need to create relation between this table

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

and then to get data from two table
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp